How do I register a middleware in Laravel 11?
Laravel 11 does not come with a middleware file and the kernel.php file has been removed altogther. So, when I create a custom middleware, how do I register it?
I do not know where to register middleware. Laravel 11 has been very confusing.

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#registering-middleware

In laravel 11 you can not register in the kernel.php the middlewares anymore. However there is plenty of other way how you can register the middlewares.
If you want it to be triggered in every call you can append it to the bootstrap/app.php .
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
     $middleware->append(YourMiddleware::class);
})

Otherwise you can add middlewares to specific route or route groups:
Route::get('/yourroute', function () {
    
})->middleware(YourMiddleware::class);

If you add a middleware to a route group but you dont want certain routes to trigger the middleware, you can use the withoutMiddleware method
Route::middleware([YourMiddleware::class])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // ...
    });
 
    Route::get('/yourroute', function () {
        // ...
    })->withoutMiddleware([YourMiddleware::class]);
});

For more information check out the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#registering-middleware

In Laravel 11, You can add/register middlewar in bootstrap/app.php
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->alias([
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    ]);
})

And In web/routes.php
Route::get('/link',[YourController::class,'method'])->name('route.name')->middleware('admin');


In Laravel 11, we can add/register middlewres in bootstrap/app.php
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
    commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
    health: '/up',
)
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->append(MiddlewareName::class);
    $middleware->alias(['apply_business_rule' => ApplyBusinessRules::class]);

})
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    //
})->create();


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

and what I I want to add the middleware in controller, can I?

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v6/basic-usage/middleware#content-package-middleware
attached documentation for spatie permission with similar approach to register middleware for route.

In bootstrap\app.php file add only this line to register new middleware after create it :
$middleware->alias([

       'isName'=>IsName::class,  //this is new middleware that i created it 

        ]);

All code will be like this :
<?php 

use App\Http\Middleware\IsName;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;


return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))

    ->withRouting(

        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',

        api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',

        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',

        health: '/up',

    )->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {

//this is new middleware that i created it

        $middleware->alias([

            'isName'=>IsName::class,

        ]);

    })

    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {

        //

    })->create();


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
